# IntelliJ cannot resolve one annotation file

Tags: intellij-idea

I have an @interface file which Intellij IDEA Ultimate cannot resolve. I've tried invalidating caches and restarting and deleting the file and recreating from subversion ( a colleague on community edition doesn't see this issue ).

I have two other annotations in the same package which work perfectly. The file is showing as classname.groovy instead of classname in my project view and doesn't have any syntax highlighting in the file.

It still compiles and runs fine but it's starting to bug me, any other suggestions?